How to run scorm file in html or javascript?
I want to play the scorm file using HTML or Javascript. 
I uploaded my scorm file to SCORM CLOUD. 
I tried with Verious Code, but I was not able to get a score or all the user information. How can I get some data using JQuery?
here is my code :


<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe
        src="https://app.cloud.scorm.com/sc/InvitationConfirmEmail?publicInvitationId=5f86e3fd-2375-45ea-ae9d-408c7d3ca54a"
        width="100%" height="600px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="SCORM_API_wrapper.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('iframe').on('load', function () {
            alert("Frame Loaded");
            var scorm = pipwerks.SCORM; // Assuming you're using the pipwerks SCORM wrapper
            var scormInitialized = scorm.init();
            if (scormInitialized) {
                alert("Intigrated");
            } else {
                alert("Faild");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</html>



I will have some data like this:

user information
score
current page and prev page

I try with May code, but I am not getting proper output. I tried to implement the scorm API, but I failed. I am not getting anything.
First One :
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('iframe').on('load', function () {
            alert("Frame Loaded");
            var scorm = pipwerks.SCORM; // Assuming you're using the pipwerks SCORM wrapper
            var scormInitialized = scorm.init();
            if (scormInitialized) {
                alert("Intigrated");
            } else {
                alert("Faild");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

Secound Try :
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('iframe').on('load', function () {
            alert("Frame Loaded");
            var scorm = pipwerks.SCORM; // Assuming you're using the pipwerks SCORM wrapper
            var scormInitialized = scorm.init();
            if (scormInitialized) {
                alert("Intigrated");
            } else {
                alert("Faild");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

